# Input data from CSV to PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Hi all I have this basic script

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "F:\Local_Users\HRosehill" -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum | 
Select-Object @{Name="Size(GB)";Expression={("{0:N2}" -f($_.Sum/1gb))}}
```

I need to replace `"F:\Local_Users\HRosehill"` with input from a list of users in a CSV how do I do this

Comment: Using `Import-Csv` with a loop of your choice. If the csv has headers, you will have to reference the proper one as well.

Comment: sorry I am new to this game can you give me an example

Comment: No worries, here's a [link](https://adamtheautomator.com/import-csv-foreach/) that shows you just this.

Answer (score 0):

As a comment said, the [`import-csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7.2) commandlet will import a properly formatted csv file into a powershell object.

**Example of an input file:**

```
F:\Local_Users\HRosehill
F:\Local_Users\username1
F:\Local_Users\username2
```

**Code**

The code below introduces the loop for using the imported names.
The delimiter can be changed with the `-delimiter` param, the header can be forced with the `-header` param

```
$usernames = import-csv mynames.csv -header username 
$usernames | foreach-object { 
    Get-ChildItem -Path $_.username -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
    Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum | 
    Select-Object @{Name="Size(GB)";Expression={("{0:N2}" -f($_.Sum/1gb))}
}
```